# R - Change values of a dataframe column based on a second dataframe

Tags: r

I need to change de names of the first column (ID_REF) of a dataframe based on the values of a second dataframe (column Gene_SYMBOL), matched by the first column of both dataframes (ID_REF and IlmnID).

```
df1
ID_REF  Sample1 Sample2 Sample3
cg00000292  0.2841738   1.212398    0.5326877
cg00002426  -4.7278154  -4.217920   -4.1224573
cg00003994  -5.7353341  -5.966922   -6.2235540

df2
IlmnID  NameIlmnStrand  AddressA_ID Gene_Symbol 
cg00002426  cg00002426  TOP SLMAP
cg00005847  cg00005847  BOT HOXD3
cg00000292  cg00000292  TOP ATP2A1
cg00006414  cg00006414  BOT ZNF398
cg00003994  cg00003994  TOP MEOX2
```

my output:

```
new_df
    Gene_Symbol Sample1 Sample2 Sample3
    ATP2A1  0.2841738   1.212398    0.5326877
    SLMAP   -4.7278154  -4.217920   -4.1224573
    MEOX2   -5.7353341  -5.966922   -6.2235540
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would just be a simple `inner_join`. You can use the `dplyr` package, or use `merge` from base R. Note that if there is no ID_REF that matches in df, the line will be omitted by using `inner_join`.

```
library(dplyr)

new_df <- inner_join(df1, df2, by = c("ID_REF" = "IlmnID")) %>%
               select(Gene_Symbol, Sample1, Sample2, Sample3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Base package:

```
merge(df2[ , c("NameIlmnStrand", "Gene_Symbol")], df1,
      by.x = "NameIlmnStrand", by.y = 'ID_REF',
      all.y = TRUE)[ ,-1]
```

**Ouput**

```
 Gene_Symbol    Sample1   Sample2    Sample3
1      ATP2A1  0.2841738  1.212398  0.5326877
2       SLMAP -4.7278154 -4.217920 -4.1224573
3       MEOX2 -5.7353341 -5.966922 -6.2235540
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1<- data.frame(
  ID_REF=c("cg00000292", "cg00002426", "cg00003994"),
  sample1 = rnorm(3),
  Sample2 = rnorm(3),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  IlmnID = c("cg00000292", "cg00002426", "cg00003994"),
  Gene_Symbol= c("SLMAP", "ATP2A", "MEOX2"),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)


# If you are sure that all IDs are included in df2
df1$ID_REF <- df2$Gene_Symbol[df2$IlmnID == df1$ID_REF]

#otherwise use sapply
df1$ID_REF <- sapply(df1$ID_REF , function(x) {
  if (x %in% df2$IlmnID) {
    df2$Gene_Symbol[df2$IlmnID == x]
  } else {
    NA
  }})
```